# How to convert minus hex value to String and byte array

Tags: java, string, hex

I want to convert decimal -10 value to hex in a String and byte array format.

I have tried

```
String minHex = Integer.toHexString(Integer.valueOf(-10));
System.out.println(minHex);
```

Which results in **fffffff6**, and I think it is not correct. And for converting byte array I am using below function which I found from

[Convert a string representation of a hex dump to a byte array using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java)

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                                 + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }
        return data;
}
```

So also not sure it will work for minus hex value or not.

Comment: your result is in twos complement form - do this (0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1010) binary of 10 considering a 32 bit integer you have. Now take the inverse of all the digits (1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0101) and add 1 to the result. You will get what you got above fffffff6. It is signed.

Answer (score 0):

To convert an hex to a `String` the way you expect it i.e. `-10` is converted to `-a`, use:

```
String hex = Integer.toString(-10, 16);
```

To convert to a `byte` array, simply convert the `int` to a `byte` array, it is represented the same way:

```
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(-10).array();
```

Comment: Thanks Jean. But byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(-10).array(); will give bytes presentation of Integer -10 but I want bytes presentation for Hex -10. What to do for that?

Comment: It is exactly the same.